# RStudio - Assigning a keyboard shortcut for read.clipboard()

Tags: r, rstudio

I would like to a sign a keyboard shortcut to `read.clipboard()`, perhaps <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>

Working with directories often, this would be most useful.

Comment: I dont think you can do this directly but I presume you can do this by making an `addin`. Any `addin` can then be set as a shortcut, https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/

Comment: Crikey, thought this post had been lost to the sands of time! Many thanks for your response I shall investigate.....

Comment: Rather straightforward. Many thanks